# Send parameters to another page

Tags: javascript, extjs, url-parameters

I have a mystic problem with sending parametrs from one page to another.

In one of ExtJs methods i send parameter by POST to another page:

```
autoLoad : {  
url : url_servlet+'form.jsp',  
params: str,
scripts: true  
}
```

But i dont know how to get this parametr in JavaScript. Okey i says, and sent parameter in url:

```
 url : url_servlet+'form.jsp?ss=333'
```

And in another page:

```
            function param(Name){
            var Params = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
            var variable = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < Params.length; i++){
                if(Params[i].split("=")[0] == Name){
                    if (Params[i].split("=").length > 1)
                        variable = Params[i].split("=")[1];
                return variable;
                }
            }
            return "";
        } 

        var s =param('ss');
        alert(s);
```

And see empty alert.

in firebug i try:

```
window.location.search
```

and get `" "`.

Whats wrong? I read several examples and everywere see code like this.

Comment: If `location.search` is empty, obviously `param('ss')` will be empty too; so look at the browser location bar when the page has loaded. If you see `ss=xyz` your code should work just fine.

Comment: in browser location bar i see `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/gis;jsessionid=01381E108A70601DEF59EC27C27B9F2E‌` but dont kwon what is mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's likely going on here is that ExtJS loads an entire page from a remote location into the current page.

When this happens, the code that gets run as a result of the load, will execute in the current page (which probably doesn't have the `ss=xyz` parameter at all).

However, your `form.jsp` should have access to the query string and can inject that into the page it returns to ExtJS.

Another option is to somehow pass that data from JavaScript once the page is loaded, but I don't know enough about ExtJS to tell you how that could be done.

Comment: So i gonna use some thing like this: `First page-->server-->Second page`? Can i put Java code in `form.jsp` get parameters from first page by POST and send it in JavaScript in `form.jsp`?

Comment: @KliverMax The `ss` parameter is part of the URL, not the POST data; but yes, that would be my suggestion.

Comment: And i cant do this in `form.jsp` : String str=request.getParameter("ss");?

Comment: @KliverMax Yeah, `request.getParameter()` should work as expected; if `null` is returned that means it just doesn't exist according to Java docs. Unfortunately, `jsp` is not my field of expertise.

Comment: Yeah. I try `String str=request.getParameter("ss");` and use parameter in JS using `<%=str%>` and its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get POST parameters from javascript. POST parameters are to the server and javascript is on the client side..

If its a GET then you could use [parseUri library](http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/)

```
var value = uri.queryKey['param'];
```

Comment: Okey. How about send with url?

Comment: -1. The parameter `ss` should be available from query parameters if the page is like `form.jsp?ss=123`.

Comment: @Jack That is a GET request not POST

Comment: @sheldonCooper  can you give example?

Comment: @Jack  but what i gonna do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below function ?

```
 function param(Name){
            var Params = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
            var variable = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < Params.length; i++){
                if(Params[i].split("=")[0] == Name){
                    variable = Params[i].split("=")[1];
                    return variable;
                }
            }
            if(variable=="") return variable;

        } 
    var s =param('ss');
    alert(s);
```

Comment: @KliverMax, What is the url in Browser Location bar ? Are you sure you tested modified function ?

Comment: in browser location bar i see `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/gis;jsessionid=01381E108A70601DEF59EC27C27B9F2E`

Comment: If there is no parameter "ss" in this url, how will you get it?  Above function works only when url is of the form http://localhost:8080//web/guest/gis?ss=333&param1=444&param2=555